# What is the probability that $P(Y>X)$ when $Y$ and $X$ are independent?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $Y\sim N(8.30;0.02^2)$ and $X\sim N(6.60;0.01^2)$. What is the probability that $P(Y>X)$ when $Y$ and $X$ are independent?

My solution so far:

Since $Y$ and $X$ are independent, $$Y+X\sim N(\mu_Y+\mu_X,\sigma^2_Y+\sigma^2_X).$$

Now

$$Y-X\sim N(1.7;0.02236^2).$$

The probability can be written

$$P(Y>X)=P(Y-X>0)=1-P(Y-X\le0)$$

and since the probability has to be greater or equal to zero,
$$1-P(Y-X=0).$$

I don't know if I have done correctly so far and I don't know how to go on from here.

Comment: I don't understand your last step. In your opinion, what needs to be positive?

Comment: You've got the law of $Y-X$ properly. Normalize it so that you can express $Y-X > 0$ in terms of a  standard normal variable.

Comment: Just as a side comment, that is so far out on the tail that it's a non-trivial task to compute what's beyond it.  I suppose one could just round off, but that doesn't seem very interesting to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $$P(Y>X)=P(Y-X>0)=1-P(Y-X\le0)$$

Up to here it is right. Next we have to know how $Y-X$ is distributed.

1. The difference of two normal distributed variables are normal distributed normal as well.
2. So the expected value is $\mathbb E(Y-X)=\mathbb E(Y)-\mathbb E(X)$ (linearity of expectation).
3. Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent the covariance is $0$. Thus $Var(Y-X)=Var(Y)+Var(X)+2\cdot cov(X,Y)=Var(Y)+Var(X)$

Combine these three information.

Edit: The variance is just $0.01^2+0.02^2=0.0005$. There is no need to square the approximated square root: $0.02236^2=0.0004999696$. This is not the exact value.

Comment: No: We *do* need the square-root of the variance to standardise . Take $Z\sim\mathcal N(0,1^2)$, $X\sim\mathcal N(\mu_{\small X},\sigma_{\small X}^2)$, and independent $Y\sim\mathcal N(\mu_{\small Y},\sigma_{\small Y}^2)$ then:$$\mathsf P(Y-X\leqslant 0)=\mathsf P\left(Z\leqslant\tfrac{0-(\mu_{\small Y}-\mu_{\small X})}{\surd(\sigma_{\small Y}^2+\sigma_{\small X}^2)}\right)$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp I´ve meant this here: $Y-X\sim N(1.7;0.02236^2)$. Better: $Y-X\sim N(1.7;0.0005)$